# 3D construction

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, structures, statics, industrial-engineering

Can someone please tell you what to start with to construct a Kids Bike Trailer as 3D.

[image]

It should select material and geometry. I think I should start sketching with forces (children's weight) and type of load (whether it is tensile, compressive or torsional), then select the appropriate material for it. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3):

There are several pages about building kids trailer:

[New EU Standard EN 15918:2011 for Bicycle Trailers](http://www.industrial-newsroom.com/news-detail/t/new-eu-standard-en-159182011-for-bicycle-trailers/)

[Bicycle trailer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_trailer)

There is mentioned EU standard:

A voluntary European standard (EN 15918) for two-wheel bicycle trailers was published in September 2011.

This standard applies to trailers carrying cargo and/or up to 2 passengers, and enforces a maximum gross weight of 60 kg. There are many safety-related requirements, including restraints, structural integrity, stability, small parts, sharp edges, etc.

You should check if your country has national regulations because they supercede EU regulations.

My toughts about design process:

You can make 3d model using software like Solidworks and also run structural anlysis, check stresses and deformations. Maybe use parametric model and later optimize construction when you see stress profile. Also check available materials, aluminium alloys are used often for bikes, light and not as expensive as carbon fiber, shaping and connecting parts may be problem with sophisticated materials. 
Stability should be also your main concern and I would advise getting this EU standard.

Comment: many thanks for very helpful tips
I have downloaded the norm, it contains many guidelines that are helpful for me.

Comment: no problem, I just searched google and was surprised that there is EU norm, though it shouldn't be surprising as bicycles are part of the traffic and their parts or additions should be safe and children friendly. we were taught at university to always check for standards and regulations which apply to our problem.